# Change iDisplayLength in wpDataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatables

On [my site](http://baudirekt.itstoolong.com/testseite_preissystem/) I am using the plugin [wpDataTables](http://wpdatatables.com) (based on jQuery DataTables). For example, when I type `HB` into the search field, I get `10` results (prices) but I only need `6`.

So I want to change the `iDisplayLengt`h from `10` to `6` but it's not working as suggested @ datatables.net

Here are some [Front-end callbacks via JS](http://wpdatatables.com/documentation/information-for-developers/front-end-callbacks/). Would it be possible via these front-end callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the video on [Using filters and actions](http://wpdatatables.com/video-course/using-filters-and-hooks/) where author of wpdatatables explains how to do almost exactly what you want.

Basically you need to add the following code to `functions.php` of your WordPress theme.

Please note that this code will affect all tables on your site. If you want to target a specific table then you need to change `iDisplayLength` param only when `$table_id` equals to your table ID.

```
function mytheme_wpdatatables_filter_table_description($object, $table_id){
   $object->dataTableParams->iDisplayLength = 6;

   return $object;
}
add_filter('wpdatatables_filter_table_description', 'mytheme_wpdatatables_filter_table_description', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much.

Comment: Here is another issue:

As an example, the values D and DH have different prices. 

In the search field, when I type in D I get a wrong result (=wrong price). I understand the „logic“ behind it. Because D is included in DH.

Is there any way to say: If I type in D then result = price for D (and not DH)?

Thanks.

Comment: @user3350511, that may be possible with JavaScript. I would suggest starting a new question since this will require a different approach/solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right. New question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611525/wrong-results-in-datatable