# Perform exact match when searching

Tags: wordpress, datatables

On [my site](http://baudirekt.itstoolong.com/preissystem-eh-125/) I am using the plugin [wpDataTables](http://wpdatatables.com) based on [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/).

My first column in the price list table contains values - `AUR`, `D`, `DH`, etc. Table is programmed to show only first 6 results out of many.

Here is the problem: If I want user to find value `D` and user types in the search field `D`, you'll get a list with values `DH`.

It happens because by default jQuery DataTables plugin finds records that contain value `D` (such as `DH`, etc), but I want it to perform exact match.

Please see [Excel spreadsheet](http://baudirekt.itstoolong.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/baudirektEH125.xlsx) containing all records for reference.

Comment: Where have you implemented the logic to search the input query ?

Comment: It's in an excel sheet: http://baudirekt.itstoolong.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/baudirektEH125.xlsx

Comment: I need to see the logic..Can you share that ?

Comment: Sorry for my english. 

The prices are for different regions in Germany. The letters (one, two or three letters) are based on german license plates. So region 1 is VEC, region 2 are HB, CLP, DH and so. If you want to see your price you just type in the letters for a given region.

The .js from datatables is here: http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: Found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match/23931504#23931504

Would this solve the problem? 

Anyway, I am getting closer but I can't see how to implement this.

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre
See edited question: It happens because by default jQuery DataTables plugin finds records that contain value D (such as DH, etc), but I want it to perform exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this documentation and end up with something like this:

```
table.column( 1 ).search( '^My exact match$', true, false );
```

You can also use quotes when you input or add them before passing to the search function:

```
 table.search( '"My exact match"' );
```

Documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid I don't know how to implement this the right way.

Comment: @user3350511 You'd need to show us all of your code in order to get more help.